# Switch statement using variables in the case condition

Tags: maya, mel

Is it possible to create `Switch` statements that use variables in the `case` condition, in Maya Mel Script language?

Something along the lines (stupid example for the sake of explanation):

```
$val1 = "foo";
$val2 = "bar";
// imagine $input as an argument of some proc
switch ($input)
{
case $val1:
    print "Input is 'foo'";
    break;

case $val2:
    print "Input is 'bar'";
    break;
}
```

P.s. I tried that and it didn't work, but you might know of another option.

Thanks a lot

Comment: By the way, this is more of a curiosity question. I can always replace it with `if` statements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables as case values directly, but you can build a string containing the code that you want to execute, with variables replaced with their values, and pass that string to the eval function:

```
$val1 = "foo";
$val2 = "bar";
// imagine $input as an argument of some proc
string $cmd;
$cmd =  "switch (\"" + $input + "\")";
$cmd += "{";
$cmd += "case \"" + $val1 + "\":";
$cmd += "    print \"Input is 'foo'\";";
$cmd += "    break;";
$cmd += "case \"" + $val2 + "\":";
$cmd += "    print \"Input is 'bar'\";";
$cmd += "    break;";
$cmd += "}";
eval $cmd;
```

Comment: Thanks :) I completely forgot to mention we were trying to avoid eval but, as this answer is correct for my original question, I'll mark as correct :) Thanks a lot!